# Generic method to set attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model I have attributes: `is_a`, `is_b` and `is_c`. By default all are null.

I need APIs to set them. These attributes can be set as strictly one or in group. If I am to write APIs, I will be doing following in my model:

```
def set_as_a # strictly a
 self.update_attributes!(:is_a => true, :is_b => false, :is_c => false)
end

def set_as_b # strictly b
 self.update_attributes!(:is_a => false, :is_b => true, :is_c => false)
end
... # strictly c
def set_as_a_and_b # a and b
 self.update_attributes!(:is_a => true, :is_b => true, :is_c => false)
end
..... # so on
```

While this works, it does not look elegant. Also if in future if the set has more than 3 attributes, it will result more repetitive code. What is the correct elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: But within your domain this concept must have a name like `...enabled` or so. Or is it realy that generic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class SettableAsABC
  ATTRS = [:a, :b, :c]
  METHOD_RE = /^set_as_([[:alnum:]]+?(?:_and_[[:alnum:]]+?)*)$/

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    if name.to_s =~ METHOD_RE
      trues = $1.split('_and_').map(&:to_sym)
      attrs = Hash[ATTRS.map { |a| ["is_#{a}".to_sym, trues.include?(a)] }]
      update_attributes(attrs)
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(name, include_private = false)
    !!(name =~ METHOD_RE) || super
  end
end

a = SettableAsABC.new
a.set_as_a_and_c
```

No defining 2^N methods, just plain Ruby metaprogramming.

EDIT: Good point, @Stefan.

EDIT2: My previous edit introduced a bug. Fixed now.

EDIT3: TIL about `respond_to_missing?`

Comment: You should also implement `respond_to_missing?`

Comment: Never thought this way, +1.

Comment: very nice approach

Comment: this is more elegant than the current accepted answer. @AndreyDeineko I will be accepting this, still thanks for your help.

Comment: @shivam no probs :)

Comment: That wasn't a typo, you should define `respond_to_missing?` instead of `respond_to?`. It allows you to get a method handle via `a.method(:set_as_a_and_c)`

Comment: @Stefan: Oh, sorry, my mind is completely absent, I totally misread what you said, and actually didn't know about `respond_to_missing?`. Thanks, will fix presently.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding something, but why not just write a single method that takes params?:

```
def set_attributes(opts = {})
  update_attributes!(opts) unless opts.none?
end
# usage
set_attributes(is_a: false, is_b: true)
```

## EDIT

To dynamically create methods for combinations of your attributes here is what I came up with:

```
attributes = %w(a b c d)
(1..attributes.size).flat_map { |size| attributes.combination(size).to_a }.each do |methods|
  define_method "set_as_#{methods.join('_and_')}" do
    update_attributes!(Hash[methods.map { |v| ["is_#{v}", true] }])
  end
end
```

It will generate the following menthods:

```
set_as_a
set_as_b
set_as_c
set_as_d
set_as_a_and_b
set_as_a_and_c
set_as_a_and_d
set_as_b_and_c
set_as_b_and_d
set_as_c_and_d
set_as_a_and_b_and_c
set_as_a_and_b_and_d
set_as_a_and_c_and_d
set_as_b_and_c_and_d
set_as_a_and_b_and_c_and_d
```

Comment: this should work fine, but I will then be constructing opt every time before invoking the method. Is there any possibility to make methods more self explanatory? For eg `set_a_and_b` is a clearer API. If the model can understand the method name and set required fields it will be awesome. I am not sure though if anything like that would be clean to code

Comment: @AndreyDeineko What if the number of attributes go beyond 10, the method name will be too long!

Comment: @RSB: "the method name will be too long" - I wouldn't worry about _that_. If you have 10+ methods, you should worry about number of defined methods. It's a combinatoric explosion. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, exactly. The number of methods would grow exponentially here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev could you please tell me, why defining a lot of methods is bad? I mean intuitively I realize it's something to avoid, but practically I do not know how to say whether it hurts performance/memory/whatsoever

Comment: It hurts memory, if there's too many. As for performance, the execution of `set_a_and_z` should not be impacted, but there would be a setup time (your `define_method` loop). It also might overwhelm someone exploring your library when they do `foo.methods`.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: what Amadan says.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def set_true(true_fields=[])
  attr_hash = {}
  true_fields.each { |field| attr_hash[field] = true }
  update_attributes(hash)  
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: while this works, I was hoping if the method names itself can be made dynamic to set values. Again, I am not sure if that is even possible, hence the question

Comment: Is there any specific reason behind making method names dynamic? I mean it can be achieved easily by making arguments dynamic isn't it?

Comment: it will cleaner that way. For eg. see how Rails days ago API works `3.days.ago`. Something similar

Comment: Yes but there `3` is an object of `Fixnum` that represents one value, here the values are multiple and also they are associated with object of another class. I can't think of any other way so following this answer to see if anyone else come up with something!

Comment: I think you are mistaken. Like `Fixnum` in Rails example, here all attributes belong to a same `Model` class.  I am just not sure how to construct  chaining.

Comment: The way you want the solution is not called `chaining`, its just a single method defined dynamically. Its like instead of doing `create(attr1: val1, attr2: val2)`, you define a method dynamically named `create_attr1_val1_attr2_val2`. Well that's my $0.02 on it.

Comment: I meant it more as english than programming. My bad :)